# How to install Ruby on Rails and MySql?

Tags: software-installation, mysql, ruby

How to install Ruby on Rails and MySql on my Ubuntu 10.04 OS?

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby on Rails**

> sudo apt-get install rails

For details, see the Ubuntu Help [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/ruby-on-rails.html).

---

**MySQL**

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

For details, see the Ubuntu Help [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/mysql.html).

Comment: `aptitude` is the new `apt-get`.

Comment: Yes. You should not be using apt-get for ANYTHING. It will not mark deps as automatically installed and therefor they will remain on your machine until you remove them by hand.

Comment: Actually, aptitude was last in the default install in 10.04.  Most users won't even have it on their system.

Answer (score 2):

I follow this guide every single time:

http://www.hackido.com/2009/11/install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-karmic.html

It's written for 9.10, but it works equally well for 10.04.  The only (minor) difference is that you can remove the **libmysqlclient15off** package.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**For Ruby on Rails**

For Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04 I followed this guide: [here](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/06/27/install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-10-1011-04/)!

There is a sibling for Ubuntu 11.10 [here](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/27/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-11-10/)!

Answer (score 0):

use rbenv to install ruby and rails framework 
http://www.computersnyou.com/1535/2013/03/installing-ruby-on-rail-on-ubuntu-with-rbenv-step-by-step/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For *Ruby on Rails* see this [instruction](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/rails3-install-ubuntu.html) and for mysql run command `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

To install mysql on local machine (Ubuntu OS) you nedd one client and server version of mysql. to install follow the steps

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```